# の　and が　before 丘

Tags: particles, particle-の, particle-が

光が丘　and 梅が丘　are places in Tokyo, and 平和の丘　is a place in Okinawa.

Why is the particle が　used in the first two names? Why isn't の　used like in 平和の丘?

Comment: Does 我が家 also sound strange to you?  https://search.yahoo.co.jp/search;_ylt=A2RA6IYTcBRd6goABcqJBtF7?p=%E6%88%91%E3%81%8C%E5%AE%B6&fr=top_ga1_sa&ei=UTF-8&aq=-1&oq=%E6%88%91%E3%81%8C%E5%AE%B6&at=&aa=&ai=RN6QiX29RVqJ6EjUd5BQjA&ts=8204

Comment: https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8C

Comment: @l'électeur strange is not the right word... interesting, I guess...